# Forms dynamique django

Tags: python, html, django

what I want my form to do is that when I select a student, for example, the "input" material disappears and gives way to the "input" sector.

Hi, I have a problem that I can't solve, the problem is with the django form, what I want my form to do is that when I select a student, for example, the "input" material disappears and gives way to the "input" sector. I try but I can't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.